# Datatables inline editor isn't closing after submission

Tags: jquery, datatables, jquery-datatables-editor

I'm using the jquery Datatables inline editing, with a custom ajax call. After upgrading to the latest version of the editor (v1.5.5), the inline form no longer closes after calling the success method.

Everything else works correctly, and the call is made to the API.

Any idea why it isn't closing the editor?

Here's the custom ajax call in the editor:

```
         ajax: function (method, url, data, onSuccess, onError) {

                $.ajax({
                    'type': 'POST',
                    'contentType': 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                    'url': "api/mywebservice",
                    'data': JSON.stringify({ ...my custom data...}),
                    'dataType': 'json',
                    'dataSrc': '',
                    'cache': false,
                    success: function (json) {
                        onSuccess(json);

                    },
                    error: function (xhr, error, thrown) {
                        alert("error!");
                        onError(xhr, error, thrown);   
                    }
                });
            }
```

Cross posted here: [DataTables Forum](https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/33570)

Comment: just doing your table.draw() must refresh it right? will that be helpful for you?

Answer (score 0):

A fix for this issue was posted on the forum I linked in the original question.

As of the latest version of the editor, the data returned from the server must be in a very specific format, and contain every value for the row you're editing.

See: http://editor.datatables.net/manual/server

This cannot currently be overridden.